# PHP Including a File 2 directories back

Tags: php, path, include, require

Here is my situation.  I have a **config.php** file that I would like to share between all of my folders.  It is located in my **root: includes/config.php**.

I am in my *admin* folder and am trying to include that config file.

```
// Does not work
require_once "../../includes/config.php";

// This will kind-of-work.. see below
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/config.php";
```

The problem with the second line is that I have 3 different environments.  Localhost, Development, and Production.

I define those environments and all the settings in config.php.  If I am on production, then that second line will work perfect.  But on my development and localhost environments.. the files are not in the root directory, they are in a subfolder.. so the only way for that to work would be:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sub_folder/includes/config.php";
```

Well, I have a PATH constant in my config.php file depending on the environment, but I can't access it because I am trying to include that file!

So I'm not sure the best way to approach this.. I hope this made sense.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your software should use a similar directory structure in any case. If I'll move my /usr/bin-directory to /usr/lalala/bin I musn't wonder why my programs wont launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do config file as .ini file instead of php. You have a function called

```
parse_ini_file($filePath);
```

in ini file you can define 'production', 'development', 'staging' environments.

This is the better way to go forward for scalability.

The ini file syntax is better explained in this wiki page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

If you would like to use php file you could, define your environment in config.php and wrap  if conditions on all the constants.

For, directory structure you could use

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__))
```

which is better than

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Hope this helps..

Karthik

Comment: realpath( __ DIR __ ) is equivalent to realpath(dirname(__ FILE __ ))